# Adding tooltips to a complicated SVG file

Tags: html, xml, web, svg, tooltip

I want to upload my svg to my website, and add tooltips on multiple parts that become visible on hover. Any suggestions for how to approach that?

My SVG was created on Adobe Illustrator, I tried a tutorial that said to paste the xml code into my html file and add in the tooltip libraries and work from there, but that doesnt seem very plausible, since somehow my xml file for my svg is like 250,000 lines :(

Comment: Add some code here

Comment: Since you need one tooltip at a a time I would make the tooltip an html element whose content is changing when mousing over an svg shape